# How to align text vertically in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want a script which would just paste text from current clipboard and align it in the text frame.
But I only figured out how to paste, and align it horizontally. How to do it vertically? So the text fits right in the center of the text frame.
Here what I have done so far:

```
app.paste();
app.selection[0].parentStory.justification = Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
```

Comment: vertical justification is a text frame property....so....// Get the parent story of the current selection
var myParentStory = app.selection[0].parentStory;

// Get all text frames for that parent story
var textFrames = myParentStory.textContainers;

// Loop through each text frame to set vertical alignment
for (var i = 0; i < textFrames.length; i++) {
    textFrames[i].textFramePreferences.verticalJustification = VerticalJustification.CENTER_ALIGN;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertical justification is a text frame property so you'll need to find the frames corresponding to the story. Here's a snippet that picks up where yours ends.

```
// Get the parent story of the current selection 
var myParentStory = app.selection[0].parentStory;
 
// Get all text frames for that parent story 
var textFrames = myParentStory.textContainers; 

// Loop through each text frame to set vertical alignment 
for (var i = 0; i < textFrames.length; i++) {
 textFrames[i].textFramePreferences.verticalJustification = VerticalJustification.CENTER_ALIGN; 
}
```